# Search through list of objects in efficient way mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a json that looks a bit like this in meteor.

```
{
  "_id": "someid",
  "createdAt": ISODate("2015-03-10T14:26:02.430Z"),
  "emails": [{
      "address": "raven@corvid.com",
      "verified": false
    }, {
      "address": "crow@corvid.com",
       "verified": false
  }]
}
```

I want to search the database and find if anyone has a given email, say, `crow@corvid.com`. If it were just a static value, you could do `Meteor.users.findOne({ email: "crow@corvid.com" });`, but the list makes it more complicated.

What is the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [**$elemMatch**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) operator to match the document that contains `crow@corvid.com` as address value.

```
Meteor.users.findOne({ emails: {$elemMatch: {address:"crow@corvid.com" }}})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also index the database, you can index embedded documents, your case an array `Meteor.users.createIndex( { "emails" : 1 } )`

Comment: What @Michael9 is trying to say is that you should explain your answer a bit more thoroughly. Right now your answer is of no value without an extensive search on DB indexations...

Comment: sorry i asumed too much